# EF Core 2: How to apply HasQueryFilter for all entities

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Is there any way to apply `HasQueryFilter()` globally to all my entities? I don't want to add in `ModelBuilder` one by one.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Manufacturer>().HasQueryFilter(p => p.IsActive);
```

Comment: Do you have some common base class or interface which defines the `IsActive` property?

Comment: yes I have an interface that include just IsActive property

Comment: Hope this link might help you out http://gunnarpeipman.com/2017/08/ef-core-global-query-filters/

Answer (score 15):

In case you have base class or interface defining the `IsActive` property, you could use the approach from [Filter all queries (trying to achieve soft delete)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45096799/ef-core-2-0-filter-all-queries-trying-to-achieve-soft-delete/45097532#45097532).

Otherwise you could iterate entity types, and for each type having `bool IsActive` property build dynamically filter expression using `Expression` class methods:

```
foreach (var entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
{
    var isActiveProperty = entityType.FindProperty("IsActive");
    if (isActiveProperty != null && isActiveProperty.ClrType == typeof(bool))
    {
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(entityType.ClrType, "p");
        var filter = Expression.Lambda(Expression.Property(parameter, isActiveProperty.PropertyInfo), parameter);
        entityType.QueryFilter = filter;
    }
}
```

**Update (EF Core 3.0):** Due to public metadata API breaking change (replacing many properties with `Get` / `Set` extension methods), the last line becomes

```
entityType.SetQueryFilter(filter);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45096799/ef-core-2-0-filter-all-queries-trying-to-achieve-soft-delete/45097532#45097532 this worked for me. Thank you.

Comment: Cannot set QueryFilter property on EF Core 3. Throws System.MissingMethodException: 'Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.IMutableEntityType.set_QueryFilter(System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression)'.'

Comment: @Onur EF Core 3.0 is still in preview (beta), hence you are using it on your own risk. I will update the answer when 3.0 is released. Until then, you may take a look at [expected breaking changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#metadata-api-changes) - most likely `QueryFilter` property is replaced with `GetQueryFilter` and `SetQueryFilter` extension methods.

Comment: Thanks @IvanStoev, switched to stable EF Core 2.2.4 version and it worked.

Comment: Our database uses a StatusCode string instead of an bool. How would I alter the lamba expression above to compare property to a string of == "Active"?

Comment: @ModestMonk Use `Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(parameter, "StatusCode"), Expression.Constant("Active"))` as body of the lambda.

Comment: in 3.1.5 last line not working. I replaced with `entityType.SetQueryFilter(filter);` and its working again.

Answer (score 2):

For those looking to implement Ivan's answer in EF Core 3.0, note the necessary change in the last line:

```
foreach (var entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
{
    var isActiveProperty = entityType.FindProperty("IsActive");
    if (isActiveProperty != null && isActiveProperty.ClrType == typeof(bool))
    {
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(entityType.ClrType, "p");
        var filter = Expression.Lambda(Expression.Property(parameter, isActiveProperty.PropertyInfo), parameter);
        MutableEntityTypeExtensions.SetQueryFilter(entityType, filter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, i used the code below: 

`var parameter = Expression.Parameter(entity.ClrType, "p");
                    var PropertyOrField = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, "IsActive");
                    
                    modelBuilder.Entity(entity.ClrType)
                        .HasQueryFilter(Expression.Lambda(
                            Expression.Equal(PropertyOrField, Expression.Constant(true)), parameter));`

Answer (score 1):

Here is extention method for EF Core version 6

```
  public static void ApplySoftDeleteQueryFilter(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  {
    var entityTypes = modelBuilder.Model
    .GetEntityTypes();

    foreach (var entityType in entityTypes)
    {
      var isActiveProperty = entityType.FindProperty("IsActive");
      if (isActiveProperty != null && isActiveProperty.ClrType == typeof(bool))
      {
        var entityBuilder = modelBuilder.Entity(entityType.ClrType);
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(entityType.ClrType, "e");
        var methodInfo = typeof(EF).GetMethod(nameof(EF.Property))!.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(bool))!;
        var efPropertyCall = Expression.Call(null, methodInfo, parameter, Expression.Constant("IsActive"));
        var body = Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionType.Equal, efPropertyCall, Expression.Constant(true));
        var expression = Expression.Lambda(body, parameter);
        entityBuilder.HasQueryFilter(expression);
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In .Net 7 this works.

For all entities;

It looks as IsActive=true and IsDeleted=false.

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        var entityTypes = builder.Model.GetEntityTypes();

        foreach (var entityType in entityTypes)
        {
            var isActiveProperty = entityType.FindProperty("IsActive");
            if (isActiveProperty != null && isActiveProperty.ClrType == typeof(bool))
            {
                var entityBuilder = builder.Entity(entityType.ClrType);
                var parameter = Expression.Parameter(entityType.ClrType, "e");
                var methodInfo = typeof(EF).GetMethod(nameof(EF.Property))!.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(bool))!;
                var efPropertyCall = Expression.Call(null, methodInfo, parameter, Expression.Constant("IsActive"));
                var body = Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionType.Equal, efPropertyCall, Expression.Constant(true));
                var expression = Expression.Lambda(body, parameter);
                entityBuilder.HasQueryFilter(expression);
            }

            var isDeleteProperty = entityType.FindProperty("IsDeleted");
            if (isDeleteProperty != null && isDeleteProperty.ClrType == typeof(bool))
            {
                var entityBuilder = builder.Entity(entityType.ClrType);
                var parameter = Expression.Parameter(entityType.ClrType, "e");
                var methodInfo = typeof(EF).GetMethod(nameof(EF.Property))!.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(bool))!;
                var efPropertyCall = Expression.Call(null, methodInfo, parameter, Expression.Constant("IsDeleted"));
                var body = Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionType.Equal, efPropertyCall, Expression.Constant(false));
                var expression = Expression.Lambda(body, parameter);
                entityBuilder.HasQueryFilter(expression);
            }
        }
    }
```