# EFCore 3.1 Adding default shadow properties and use them for softdelete

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core, ef-core-3.0

I am developing an application with C# .NET Core 3.1 and EFCore. Based on [this document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45812459/ef-core-2-apply-hasqueryfilter-for-all-entity), I tried to add new column and use Queryfilter.

```
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new UserEntityTypeConfiguration());
            ....
            //Other configurations
            ...

            // Assures consistent naming and configuration of audit fields.
            foreach (IMutableEntityType entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes().Where(item => !item.IsOwned()))
            {
                //Settings related to softdelete
                modelBuilder.Entity(entityType.Name).Property<bool>(nameof(DefaultColumnName.IsDeleted)).HasDefaultValue(false);
                var IsDeletedProperty = entityType.FindProperty(nameof(DefaultColumnName.IsDeleted));
                if (IsDeletedProperty != null && IsDeletedProperty.ClrType == typeof(bool))
                {
                    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(entityType.ClrType, "p");
                    var prop = Expression.Property(parameter, IsDeletedProperty.PropertyInfo);
                    var filter = Expression.Lambda(Expression.Not(prop), parameter);
                    MutableEntityTypeExtensions.SetQueryFilter(entityType, filter);
                }
            }
```

However, when I migrate with `dotnet ef migrations add Init`, following error appears and cannot migrate well.

```
Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'property')
```

According to my investigation, this error occurrs at this line, but I do not know how to fix the problem.

```
var prop = Expression.Property(parameter, IsDeletedProperty.PropertyInfo);
```

Could anyone tell me how to fix the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shadow properties are not real properties of a class, hence have no associated `PropertyInfo` or `FieldInfo`. As explained in [Accessing shadow properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/shadow-properties#accessing-shadow-properties)
:

> 1. Shadow property values can be obtained and changed through the `ChangeTracker` API
> 2. Shadow properties can be referenced in LINQ queries via the `EF.Property` static method

The second applies to filter expressions as well. So you need property accessor like

```
EF.Property<bool>(p, "IsDeleted")
```

which for your code means changing the line in question as follows

```
var prop = Expression.Call(
    typeof(EF), nameof(EF.Property), new[] { typeof(bool) },
    parameter, Expression.Constant(IsDeletedProperty.Name));
```