# Using EF Core HasQueryFilter on navigation properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to apply a filter to my queries for multi-tenancy but it doesn't allow me to apply the filter when the property is part of a navigation property:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Level>().HasQueryFilter(lvl => lvl.SchoolYear.TenantId == _tenantProvider.TenantId);
```

Here, Level is the property I want filtered but the property to use for filtering which is TenantId is is inside Level.SchoolYear.

If its a top-level property it works fine. How can I apply a global filter when the property I need for filtering is a navigation property?

Answer (score 7):

As said, these model level filters are not (yet) implemented for navigation properties. Which is sad, because people may not be aware of this restriction and count on it in a multi-tenant architecture. Everybody knows that making errors in a multi-tenant application may be the death of your company, so it's pretty vital to do this right.

Once you've chosen for tenant separation by `TenantId` (and not the safer schema-per-tenant or database-per-tenant), and knowing this current restriction in EF-core, you may want to build in a safeguard that at least you'll never mix up tenant data when saving changes.

This safeguard could be implemented by defining an interface:

```
public interface IHasTenantId
{
    int TenantId { get; }   
}
```

... to be implemented by each entity having a `TenantId`.

Then in an override of `SaveChanges` in the `DbContext` subclass there can be a check if all `TenantId`s in a change set are identical:

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    var distinctTenantIdsCount = this.ChangeTracker.Entries<IHasTenantId>()
                                     .Select(e => e.Entity.TenantId)
                                     .Distinct().Count();
    if(distinctTenantIdsCount > 1)
    {
        // Throw an exception and handle it.
    }
    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: By the way, [row-level security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/row-level-security) is a much better safeguard.

Answer (score 5):

You can't. It's a documented limitation of the current (as of EF Core 2.0.1) [Global Query Filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters) implementation:

> Filters cannot contain references to navigation properties.

It's tracked by [#8881: Allow to use navigations in model level entity filters](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/8881) enhancement request, but unfortunately has no concrete milestone assigned, which means we don't know if and when it will be fixed.

Comment: Yeah, too bad they rolled this out as a half-baked feature. Another source of confusion and SO questions.

Comment: @GertArnold Yeah :( I already had to deal with the [second limitation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47268072/ef-core-2-0-0-query-filter-is-caching-tenantid-updated-for-2-0-1/47270953#47270953) which is also makes no logical sense to me since the "regular" query filters has no such requirements.

Comment: This limitation was removed in EF Core 2.1. You can now use HasQueryFilters accross navigation properties.

https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/8881