# EF Core Global Query Filter for SaveChanges (Update, Delete)

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, global-query-filter

### TL;DR;

Is there any way to apply a query filter to `WHERE` clause of generated `UPDATE` and `DELETE` statement using EF Core when you call `SaveChanges`? (Quite similar to [Global query filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) which work just for `SELECT` scenarios.)

---

[Global query filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) work well for `SELECT` scenarios by adding additional criteria to `WHERE` clause of generated `SELECT` statement, but they don't do the same for `UPDATE` and `DELETE` statements when you call `SaveChanges` method of the DbContext and I wonder if it's possible to apply a query filter to `WHERE` clause of generated `UPDATE` and `DELETE` statement using EF Core when you call `SaveChanges`? The same way that it works by `HasQueryFilter` for `SELECT` statements.

I'm going to use such feature for a multi-tenancy scenario in a small application and I'm able to handle this requirement in other layers or by overriding SaveChanges and checking if the deleted or modified entity belongs to the right tenant; however, because of performance and security considerations, I prefer query filter approach.

### More context

One of the common scenarios of query filters is Multi-tenancy. Data of a tenant should be protected against reading and modification by other tenants:

- Reading by another tenant: Registering a global query filter using `HasQueryFilter` works well.
- Modification by another tenant: How to do it in EF DbContext?

You can take a look at [query filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) on Microsoft Docs or their [sample code](https://github.com/dotnet/EntityFramework.Docs/tree/master/samples/core/Querying/QueryFilters?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) on GitHub.

**Why am I looking for query filters for UPDATE and DELETE?**

The main reasons are:

- Performance considerations
- Security considerations

After all, we have query filter for SELECT statement, why shouldn't we have for UPDATE and DELETE?

**Performance considerations**

I'm able to handle this requirement in other layers, like API, DAL, BLL or by overriding `SaveChanges` and checking if the deleted or modified entity belongs to the right tenant; The main reason that I prefer to not do it in BLL or SaveChanges, is because of performance. A WHERE clause will be evaluated at database server side, it's secure and also high performance, quite similar to global query filters.

For example, for a Delete scenario, an obvious answer could be something like this:

```
var entity = db.BlogPosts.Find(id);
if(entity!=null)
    db.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Deleted;
db.SaveChanges();
```

Which is basically a `SELECT` and then a `DELETE`.

But, I prefer to delete like this, which is just a `DELETE` statement:

```
db.Entry(new BlogPost() { Id = id }).State = EntityState.Deleted;
db.SaveChanges();
```

**Security Considerations**

The other thing is, first of all, these entities doesn't necessary have a `TenantId` in `DbContext.Entries`. On the other hand, even if they have a value for their `TenantId`, the value is not reliable, because it may have been changed. `BlogPost.Id = 2` may belong to tenant 2, while tenant 1 is trying to modify or delete it.

Comment: I think [EntityFrameworkCore.Triggered](https://github.com/koenbeuk/EntityFrameworkCore.Triggered) can do what you need. There are many other [EF Core Tools & Extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/extensions/). Judging by the description, a couple of them can also be useful.

Comment: Use schema per tenant. Much safer. All EF commands will go to one schema and never cross the tenant boundary. Not to mention that it also strongly simplifies the data model.

Comment: @GertArnold I agree. But I still wonder if a similar approach like `HasQueryFilter` is available (or could be easily made) for DbContext to apply filter on `SaveChanges` by adding criteria to UPDATE and DELETE statements.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Thanks for the links, though I prefer to not introduce a dependency to a 3rd party libraries just because of this requirement.

Comment: I overrode savechanges so I could re-validate all added/modified objects before allowing them to be saved. So... how about a validation attribute to confirm that the tenant is valid for this user?

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Yes, as I already mentioned in the post and also in one of the answers. overriding SaveChanges and checking whether entity belongs to the tenant, is an option. I also am able to handle it in other layers. But in general I'm looking for adding `WHERE` clause because of the performance.

Comment: Attribute also can do the trick just in case the attribute is somehow a remote attribute (validate using database). But in terms of performance, `WHERE` clause is much better. The same way that `HasQueryFilter` works for `SELECT`. I've already shared a quick and dirty example of how to do it using Command Interceptors, but i'm open for better suggestions.

Comment: I remembered [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47485336/861716). Could be helpful for you.

Comment: @GertArnold Thanks for sharing. As I already mentioned in the question, I'm able to handle this inside `SaveChanges` or in other layers (like at beginning of BLL methods). The main reason that I prefer to not do it in BLL or SaveChanges, is because of performance. A `WHERE` clause will be evaluated at database server side, it's secure and also high performance, quite similar to global query filters.

Comment: @GertArnold On the other hand, inside `SaveChanges` I cannot rely on tenant id field of the entity in edit or delete scenarios. Tenant 1 may try to delete a BlogPost by id=2, while the entity that I've attached to the context doesn't have a TenantId: `db.Entry(new BlogPost() { Id = 2 }).State = EntityState.Deleted;`

Comment: @GertArnold An obvious solution (in other layers) is first try to load the BlogPost like `var  entity = db.BlogPosts.Find(id);` then if it doesn't find it (because of global query filters that I have inside DbContext) then throw exception. But here you see I have an additional `SELECT` statement, while for a delete, I can delete without loading the entity `db.Entry(new BlogPost() { Id = 2 }).State = EntityState.Deleted;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Update**: There is no built-in support for this at the moment, however I've booked an [issue/feature suggestion in EF Core repository](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/24122?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235). It may be implemented in future as part of batch operation scenarios or as an improvement to SaveChanges. You may want to share your idea about the feature there.

I couldn't find any built-in feature which works like global query filter for update and delete statements.

An option, to apply a global query filter for update and delete statements, you can consider [Command Interceptors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/interceptors?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235). They allow you to modify the command before execution and for example add a query filter to the command text.

As an example, the following code shows how you can modify the UPDATE or DETELE statement and add a clause like `WHERE TenantId = @__TenantId__ AND` . This way, you can be sure the updating or deleting data belongs the the tenant and a tenant cannot modify or delete data of another tenant.

To do so, create a [DbCommandInterceptor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.diagnostics.dbcommandinterceptor?view=efcore-5.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) to intercept update and delete command:

```
public class BlogPostsCommandInterceptor : DbCommandInterceptor
{
    ITenantProvider tenantProvider;
    public BlogPostsCommandInterceptor(ITenantProvider tenantProvider)
    {
        this.tenantProvider = tenantProvider;
    }
    public override InterceptionResult<DbDataReader> ReaderExecuting(
        DbCommand command, CommandEventData eventData, 
        InterceptionResult<DbDataReader> result) {
        ModifyCommand(command);
        return base.ReaderExecuting(command, eventData, result);
    }
    public override ValueTask<InterceptionResult<DbDataReader>> ReaderExecutingAsync(
        DbCommand command, CommandEventData eventData,
        InterceptionResult<DbDataReader> result,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = default) {
        ModifyCommand(command);
        return base.ReaderExecutingAsync(command, eventData, result, cancellationToken);
    }
    private void ModifyCommand(DbCommand command) {
        if (command.CommandText.StartsWith("UPDATE \"BlogPosts\"") ||
            command.CommandText.StartsWith("DELETE FROM \"BlogPosts\""))
        {
            var parameter = command.CreateParameter();
            parameter.ParameterName = "@__TenantId__";
            parameter.Value = tenantProvider.GetTenantId();
            command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
            command.CommandText = command.CommandText.Replace("WHERE",
                $"WHERE (\"TenantId\" = {parameter.ParameterName}) AND ");
        }
    }
}
```

Register the Interceptor:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(
    DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    optionsBuilder.AddInterceptors(
        new BlogPostsCommandInterceptor(tenantProvider));
}
```

This is not exactly what I was looking for; but anyways, it may be inspiring for others; And I'd be happy to receive better options, which answer the original question.

Answer (score 0):

> Modification by another tenant: How to do it in EF DbContext?

You can override SaveChanges() and verify that all the entities belong to the correct tenant.

Comment: Thanks David, I believe it's an obvious option, however as I explained in the question, I'm looking for something like HasQueryFilter to **adds a criteria to where clause of Update and Delete queries**.

Comment: You could add TenantID as a ConcurrencyToken which would add it to the WHERE clause of UPDATEs and DELETEs, and block  you from changint the TenantID.  Wouldn't help with INSERT, though.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/concurrency?tabs=data-annotations

Comment: I don't have problem for inserts; it's being handled like [this](https://github.com/dotnet/EntityFramework.Docs/blob/master/samples/core/Querying/QueryFilters/BloggingContext.cs?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235).

Comment: I'll take a look at `ConcurrencyToken`. Here, changing the TenantId is not a concern, I'll just exclude it from updates. But modifying a blog post which belongs to another tenant is a concern. Imagine a BlogPost (having an id which belongs to another tenant) has been attached to DbContext and is going to be saved on DB. An update command is going to be generated for this like `UPDATE BlogPost SET Content=@Content WHERE Id = @Id`; I would like to add `AND Tenant=tenant1` to all the update statements on BlogPost table. It's basically what `HasQueryFilter` do for the `SELECT` statements.

Comment: If you make TenantID the leading column in every PK, that would be fixed too.

Comment: I'm considering [interceptors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/interceptors?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)