# In Entity Framework Core, can you prevent an update save if an IsDeleted field is set to true

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have an `IsDeleted` flag for soft deletes and was wondering if there's a way to ensure that no saves are done if `IsDeleted == true` without loading the row and explicitly checking the value of `IsDeleted`.

Comment: With [global query filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters)?

Comment: That was my first thought, but that just stops an IsDeleted record from being visible, but not from being overwritten.

Comment: Does [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66125638/ef-core-global-query-filter-for-savechanges-update-delete) address the issue?

Comment: Yeah, so there's currently no way of doing it.   I'll just have to do it the old fashioned way, load check the value and proceed from there.   I've got some other checks and balances that need doing, about half can be done cleanly like global query filers, the rest I'll just have to make-do-and-mend with.   Thanks.