# EF Core: Soft delete with shadow properties and query filters

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-core-2.0

I've created an interface to try to do a soft delete, mixing shadow properties and query filters. But it's not working.

```
public interface IDeletableEntity {}
```

And then in my model builder

```
 builder.Model.GetEntityTypes()
                .Where(entityType => typeof(IDeletableEntity).IsAssignableFrom(entityType.ClrType))
                .ToList()
                .ForEach(entityType =>
                {
                    builder.Entity(entityType.ClrType).Property<Boolean>("IsDeleted");
                    builder.Entity(entityType.ClrType).HasQueryFilter(e => EF.Property<Boolean>(e, "IsDeleted") == false);
                });
```

But the line with the query filter doesn't compile. The error I got is "cannot convert lambda expression to type 'lambda expression' because it is not a delegate type"

If I do this it's working.

```
builder.Entity<MyEntity>().HasQueryFilter(m => EF.Property<Boolean>(m, "IsDeleted") == false);
```

there are any way to do this? It's in order to have an Interface with IDeletableEntity and not have to do it, in every Entity that I want to use a soft delete Entity

Many thanks in advance,

Answer (score 20):

`HasQueryFilter` of the non generic `EntityTypeBuilder` (as opposed to the generic `EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity>`) is almost unusable because there is no easy way to create the expected `LambdaExpression`.

One solution is to build the lambda expression by hand using the `Expression` class methods:

```
.ForEach(entityType =>
{
    builder.Entity(entityType.ClrType).Property<Boolean>("IsDeleted");
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(entityType.ClrType, "e");
    var body = Expression.Equal(
        Expression.Call(typeof(EF), nameof(EF.Property), new[] { typeof(bool) }, parameter, Expression.Constant("IsDeleted")),
    Expression.Constant(false));
    builder.Entity(entityType.ClrType).HasQueryFilter(Expression.Lambda(body, parameter));
});
```

Another one is to use a prototype expression

```
Expression<Func<object, bool>> filter = 
    e => EF.Property<bool>(e, "IsDeleted") == false;
```

and use a parameter replacer to bind the parameter with actual type:

```
.ForEach(entityType =>
{
    builder.Entity(entityType.ClrType).Property<Boolean>("IsDeleted");
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(entityType.ClrType, "e");
    var body = filter.Body.ReplaceParameter(filter.Parameters[0], parameter);
    builder.Entity(entityType.ClrType).HasQueryFilter(Expression.Lambda(body, parameter));
});
```

where `ReplaceParameter` is one of the custom helper extension method I'm using for expression tree manipulation:

```
public static partial class ExpressionUtils
{
    public static Expression ReplaceParameter(this Expression expr, ParameterExpression source, Expression target) =>
        new ParameterReplacer { Source = source, Target = target }.Visit(expr);

    class ParameterReplacer : System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor
    {
        public ParameterExpression Source;
        public Expression Target;
        protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node) => node == Source ? Target : node;
    }
}
```

But most natural solution in my opinion is to move the configuration code in a generic method and call it via reflection. For instance:

```
static void ConfigureSoftDelete<T>(ModelBuilder builder)
    where T : class, IDeletableEntity
{
    builder.Entity<T>().Property<Boolean>("IsDeleted");
    builder.Entity<T>().HasQueryFilter(e => EF.Property<bool>(e, "IsDeleted") == false);
}
```

and then

```
.ForEach(entityType => GetType()
    .GetMethod(nameof(ConfigureSoftDelete), BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static)
    .MakeGenericMethod(entityType.ClrType)
    .Invoke(null, new object[] { builder })
);
```

Comment: Thanks, you've saved me a lot of troubles here

Comment: what is `filter` in second block

Comment: @deadManN Good question, looks like I forgot to include it. Thanks for pointing that out, post updated.

Comment: thanks to you, this one bothered me for long ( i  mean the whole answer) yet still there wasn't a way to compile and use `Expression<Func<...>>(x=>x.IsDeleted)` directly, or somehow in a close way

Answer (score 18):

I've found a simple solution for my answer ;-). Thanks anyway Ivan Stoev

The interface is:

```
public interface IDeletableEntity
{
    bool IsDeleted { get; }
}
```

And in your model Builder configuration:

```
builder.Model.GetEntityTypes()
                       .Where(entityType => typeof(IDeletableEntity).IsAssignableFrom(entityType.ClrType))
                       .ToList()
                       .ForEach(entityType =>
                       {
                           builder.Entity(entityType.ClrType)
                           .HasQueryFilter(ConvertFilterExpression<IDeletableEntity>(e => !e.IsDeleted, entityType.ClrType));
                       });
```

You need to convertfilterExpression

```
private static LambdaExpression ConvertFilterExpression<TInterface>(
                            Expression<Func<TInterface, bool>> filterExpression,
                            Type entityType)
                {
                    var newParam = Expression.Parameter(entityType);
                    var newBody = ReplacingExpressionVisitor.Replace(filterExpression.Parameters.Single(), newParam, filterExpression.Body);

                    return Expression.Lambda(newBody, newParam);
                }
```

Answer (score 4):

A small enhancement to @SamazoOo's answer. You can write an extension method to make it more consistent.

```
public static EntityTypeBuilder HasQueryFilter<T>(this EntityTypeBuilder entityTypeBuilder, Expression<Func<T, bool>> filterExpression)
    {
        var param = Expression.Parameter(entityTypeBuilder.Metadata.ClrType);
        var body = ReplacingExpressionVisitor.Replace(filterExpression.Parameters.Single(), param, filterExpression.Body);

        var lambdaExp = Expression.Lambda(body, param);

        return entityTypeBuilder.HasQueryFilter(lambdaExp);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

That does not work for me, .net core 3.1, so I tried the following approach which is kinda similar :

```cs
// fetch entity types by reflection then: 

 softDeletedEntityTypes.ForEach(entityType =>
            {
                modelBuilder.Entity(entityType, builder =>
                {
                    builder.Property<bool>("IsDeleted");
                    builder.HasQueryFilter(GenerateQueryFilterExpression(entityType));
                });
            });


 private static LambdaExpression GenerateQueryFilterExpression(Type entityType)
        {            
             // the following lambda expression should be generated
             // e => !EF.Property<bool>(e, "IsDeleted")); 

            var parameter = Expression.Parameter(entityType, "e"); // e =>

            var fieldName = Expression.Constant("IsDeleted", typeof(string)); // "IsDeleted"

            // EF.Property<bool>(e, "IsDeleted")
            var genericMethodCall = Expression.Call(typeof(EF), "Property", new[] {typeof(bool)}, parameter, fieldName);

            // !EF.Property<bool>(e, "IsDeleted"))
            var not = Expression.Not(genericMethodCall);

            // e => !EF.Property<bool>(e, "IsDeleted"));
            var lambda = Expression.Lambda(not, parameter);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

What I did was

```
builder.Model.GetEntityTypes()
           .Where(p => typeof(IDeletableEntity).IsAssignableFrom(p.ClrType))
           .ToList()
            .ForEach(entityType =>
            {
                builder.Entity(entityType.ClrType)
                .HasQueryFilter(ConvertFilterExpression<IDeletableEntity>(e => !e.IsDeleted, entityType.ClrType));
            });
```

and

```
 private static LambdaExpression ConvertFilterExpression<TInterface>(
                Expression<Func<TInterface, bool>> filterExpression,
                Type entityType)
    {
        var newParam = Expression.Parameter(entityType);
        var newBody = ReplacingExpressionVisitor.Replace(filterExpression.Parameters.Single(), newParam, filterExpression.Body);

        return Expression.Lambda(newBody, newParam);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For EF core version 6.0 here is an extension function that applies "soft deleting" filter query to all entities that extends to IDeletableEntity interface.

1. nullable version *(bool? IsDeleted)*

```
    public interface IDeletableEntity
    {
      public bool? IsDeleted { get; set; }
    }
      
      public static void UseSoftDelete(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
      {
        var softDeleteEntities = modelBuilder.Model
        .GetEntityTypes()
        .Where(t => t.ClrType.IsAssignableTo(typeof(IDeletableEntity)))
        .ToArray();
        foreach (var softDeleteEntity in softDeleteEntities)
        {
            var entityBuilder = modelBuilder.Entity(softDeleteEntity.ClrType);
            var parameter = Expression.Parameter(entityType, "e");
            var methodInfo = typeof(EF).GetMethod(nameof(EF.Property))!.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(bool?))!;
            var efPropertyCall = Expression.Call(null, methodInfo, parameter, Expression.Constant(nameof(IDeletableEntity.IsDeleted)));
            var converted = Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionType.Coalesce, efPropertyCall, Expression.Constant(false));
            var body = Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionType.Equal, converted, Expression.Constant(false));
            var expression = Expression.Lambda(body, parameter);
            entityBuilder.HasQueryFilter(expression);
        }
      }
```

2. non nullable version *(bool IsDeleted)*

```
    public interface IDeletableEntity
    {
      public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    }
      
      public static void UseSoftDelete(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
      {
        var softDeleteEntities = modelBuilder.Model
        .GetEntityTypes()
        .Where(t => t.ClrType.IsAssignableTo(typeof(IDeletableEntity)))
        .ToArray();
        foreach (var softDeleteEntity in softDeleteEntities)
        {
            var entityBuilder = modelBuilder.Entity(softDeleteEntity.ClrType);
            var parameter = Expression.Parameter(entityType, "e");
            var methodInfo = typeof(EF).GetMethod(nameof(EF.Property))!.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(bool))!;
            var efPropertyCall = Expression.Call(null, methodInfo, parameter, Expression.Constant(nameof(IDeletableEntity.IsDeleted)));
            var body = Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionType.Equal, efPropertyCall, Expression.Constant(false));
            var expression = Expression.Lambda(body, parameter);
            entityBuilder.HasQueryFilter(expression);
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel the solutions involving `Expression` and `ReplacingExpressionVisitor` are too convoluted. I would write this in a more straightforward way, using reflection.

Step 1: Extract your query filter to its own method.

```
private static SetNotSoftDeletedQueryFilter<T>(ModelBuilder builder) where T : class, IDeletableEntity
{
  builder.Entity<T>().HasQueryFilter(m => EF.Property<Boolean>(m, "IsDeleted") == false);
}
```

Step 2: Get a hook to the above method via reflection.

```
private static readonly MethodInfo SetNotSoftDeletedQueryFilterMethod = typeof(ApplicationDbContext)
  .GetMethod(nameof(SetNotSoftDeletedQueryFilter), BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic)!;
```

Step 3: Invoke!

```
builder.Model.GetEntityTypes()
  .Where(entityType => typeof(IDeletableEntity).IsAssignableFrom(entityType.ClrType))
  .ToList()
  .ForEach(entityType =>
  {
    builder.Entity(entityType.ClrType).Property<Boolean>("IsDeleted");
    //builder.Entity(entityType.ClrType).HasQueryFilter(e => EF.Property<Boolean>(e, "IsDeleted") == false);
    SetNotSoftDeletedQueryFilterMethod.MakeGenericMethod(entityType.ClrType)
      .Invoke(null, new object[] { builder });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

use below code to get all entities and filter a property:

```
foreach (var entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
        {
            if (entityType.ClrType.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AuditableAttribute), true).Length > 0)
            {                                       
                modelBuilder.Entity(entityType.Name).Property<bool>("IsRemoved");                   
            }

            var isActiveProperty = entityType.FindProperty("IsRemoved");
            if (isActiveProperty != null && isActiveProperty.ClrType == typeof(bool))
            {
                var entityBuilder = modelBuilder.Entity(entityType.ClrType);
                var parameter = Expression.Parameter(entityType.ClrType, "e");
                var methodInfo = typeof(EF).GetMethod(nameof(EF.Property))!.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(bool))!;
                var efPropertyCall = Expression.Call(null, methodInfo, parameter, Expression.Constant("IsRemoved"));
                var body = Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionType.Equal, efPropertyCall, Expression.Constant(false));
                var expression = Expression.Lambda(body, parameter);
                entityBuilder.HasQueryFilter(expression);
            }                
        }
```