# How to use Interface to apply EF Core Global Query Filter

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

In order to manage soft deleted entities, I'd like to apply Global Query Filter on each entity who implements ISoftDelete, but this code does not work :

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<ISoftDelete>().HasQueryFilter(p => !p.IsDeleted);
}
```

I get this error :

```
System.ArgumentException: 'The entity type 'Shoppy.Core.Commons.ISoftDelete' provided for the argument 'clrType' must be a reference type.'
```

Is it possible to use Interface as Entity type ? Should I loop on each `modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes()` and apply query manually (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48744644/8500879)) ? Or maybe another way ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Isn't the linked question exactly the same as this one?

Comment: Shortly - yes, you should use a loop. Because the expected parameter type of the `HasQueryFilter` lambda expression should be the actual entity type, not the interface.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto not exactly. The other post has already made the choice to use a loop, even if he used also an Interface. I just wanna know if we can directly use an interface instead of a specific type.

Comment: Isn't Entity Framework telling you that you cannot?

Comment: Thanks for your input @IvanStoev. I'm gonna try with a loop. I think I'll also try with a base type to see if it's possible.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto yes you're right. I just wanted to know if there is another way (different from my implementation and from the implementation inside the other link) to apply query filters with interfaces. The "loop" way, in the other link, seems to be a good one : `Where(entityType => typeof(ISoftDelete).IsAssignableFrom(entityType.ClrType))`

Comment: You are welcome. But better not try with base class if you don't want troubles / unexpected surprises. `Entity<BaseClass>()` will cause EF to treat your `BaseClass` as entity and map it with TPH inheritance strategy in database.

Comment: Alright! Thanks for the advice.