# How to not declare key in root model in EntityFramework core

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I would like to create a base model with some common fields for all tables, like `CreatedBy` and `ModifiedBy`, but I don't want to add the key to that base model.

```
public abstract class BaseModel
{
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
}

public class Student : BaseModel
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

I am getting this error message

> The derived type cannot have KeyAttribute on property 'Id' since the
>   primary key can only be declared on the root type

.

I am using Entity Framework Core 2.

Comment: Just don't map the `BaseModel` class, only map the sub classes. Or don't use a base class and visible properties at all. These properties are perfect candidates for [shadow properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52021425/861716)

Comment: The main motivation for all of this is to add IsDeleted property in the BaseModel and to have Query filter like this `modelBuilder.Entity<BaseModel>().HasQueryFilter(p => !p.IsDeleted)` is there any way to implement this

Comment: Yes.  This answer on Soft Delete with Shadow Properties and Query Filters: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47673524/ef-core-soft-delete-with-shadow-properties-and-query-filters

Comment: @Mirhat problem is in your `DbContext` class. Please share your `DbContext` class code.

Answer (score 2):

I have received the same error and came here. Your code is not complete, but I can provide some insight based on what I have experienced. Possible causes:

1. `DbSet<BaseModel>` in your context
2. Foreign key involving base model:

   [ForeignKey(nameof(BaseModel)]
   public int SomeId { get; set; }

   public BaseModel SomeNavigationProperty { get; set; }
3. Some (navigation) property using BaseModel in any of your models (used in the db context)

   public BaseModel SomeModel { get; set; }

All these will make `add-migration` think that `BaseModel` is a model to be added and dealt with in the database context and will generate this error.