# Analyse the tables involved in an IQueryable

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have a requirement where I need to look at all of the tables involved in a query about to be run by EF Core via an IQueryable

Has anyone ever been able to do this?

Lets use an example

```cs
var cars = await (from car in DbContext.Cars
    from salesperson in DbContext.SalesPersons.Where(x=>x.Id == car.SalesPersonId)
    .Select(x=>x.Car));
```

Lets now say that there is a CountryId column in the salespersons table and the Cars table

I need to detect that the IQueryable above is using Cars and SalesPerson

Then I will add to the IQueryable so it becomes

```cs
var cars = await (from car in DbContext.Cars
    from salesperson in DbContext.SalesPersons.Where(x=>x.Id == car.SalesPersonId).Select(x=>x.Car)
    .Where(car.CountryId = 1).Where(salesPerson.CountryId = 1);
```

So we are basically adding a filter at runtime automatically

Cheers

Paul

Comment: Can you add more details? Why it is needed, because there is no documented way to do that. Also there is TPT queries, which complicates things.

Comment: Maybe you just need [Global Query Filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters). From first sight it is what is needed.

Comment: This looks powerful, but how do I get the active tenant into the TenantService as its injected as Transient (Im assumng)

Comment: Add property `TenantId` to `DbContext`

Comment: Can you add this as an answer please?

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47270953/10646316) is enough?

Comment: Yes please add this as an answer so I can accept it and your reputation will increase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not needed to analyze LINQ query for your task. For filtering by tenant there is [Global Query Filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters). After configuring EF Core should apply filter for every entity which has defined Query Filter.

```cs
public class TenantContext : DbContext
{
    public int? TenantId { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        ... // entities configuration

        modelBuilder.Entity<Some>().HasQueryFilter(e => TenantId == null || TenantId == e.TenantId)
    }
}
```

All that you need before querying data - set `TenantId` for context

```
context.TeantId = 2;
context.Some.ToList() // table will be filtered by TenantId == 2
```

I have prepared small sample how to apply tenant filter for all entities in one function call:

```cs
public class TenantContext : DbContext
{
    public int? TenantId { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        ... // entities configuration

        ApplyTenantQueryFilters(modelBuilder, "TenantId", () => TenantId);
    }

    private void ApplyTenantQueryFilters<TProp>(ModelBuilder builder, string tenantPropName, Expression<Func<TProp>> tenantPropExpr)
    {
        foreach (var entityType in builder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
        {
            var tenantProp = entityType.GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == tenantPropName);
            if (tenantProp == null)
                continue;

            var entityParam = Expression.Parameter(entityType.ClrType, "e");

            var contextTenantPropAccess = tenantPropExpr.Body;

            var propertyExpression = GetPropertyExpression(entityParam, tenantProp);
            if (propertyExpression.Type != contextTenantPropAccess.Type)
                propertyExpression = Expression.Convert(propertyExpression, contextTenantPropAccess.Type);

            // ctx.TenantId == null || ctx.TenantId == e.TenantId
            var filterBody = (Expression)Expression.OrElse(
                Expression.Equal(contextTenantPropAccess, Expression.Default(contextTenantPropAccess.Type)),
                Expression.Equal(contextTenantPropAccess,
                    propertyExpression));

            var filterLambda = entityType.GetQueryFilter();

            // we have to combine filters
            if (filterLambda != null)
            {
                filterBody = ReplacingExpressionVisitor.Replace(entityParam, filterLambda.Parameters[0], filterBody);
                filterBody = Expression.AndAlso(filterLambda.Body, filterBody);
                filterLambda = Expression.Lambda(filterBody, filterLambda.Parameters);
            }
            else
            {
                filterLambda = Expression.Lambda(filterBody, entityParam);
            }

            entityType.SetQueryFilter(filterLambda);
        }
    }

    private static Expression GetPropertyExpression(Expression objExpression, IProperty property)
    {
        Expression propExpression;
        if (property.PropertyInfo == null)
        {
            // 'property' is Shadow property, so call via EF.Property(e, "name")
            propExpression = Expression.Call(typeof(EF), nameof(EF.Property), new[] { property.ClrType },
                objExpression, Expression.Constant(property.Name));
        }
        else
        {
            propExpression = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(objExpression, property.PropertyInfo);
        }

        return propExpression;
    }
}
```

Comment: My global filter is going to be tenant id on the entity matches tenant id in the context OR tenant id on the context is null. How can we adapt the above for that?

Comment: If you look at the code it matches exactly what you need:  `ctx.TenantId == null || ctx.TenantId == e.TenantId`

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73925788/include-null-checking-in-expression-of-query-filter