# Include null checking in expression of Query Filter

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

A while back I raised [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73121768/analyse-the-tables-involved-in-an-iqueryable) for applying a query filter

However, I now have a requirement where if the property in the record of the table is null I need to include it

I have made the code a bit more generic so we just pass in a dictionary of the properties to filter and the value to filter for

```
public static class ModelBuilderExtensions
{
   public static void ApplyQueryFiltersForProperties<TProp>(this ModelBuilder builder,
        Dictionary<string, Expression<Func<TProp>>> propertiesToFilter)
    {
        foreach (var (propertyName, expression) in propertiesToFilter)
        {
            foreach (var entityType in builder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
            {
                var tenantProp = entityType.GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == propertyName);
                if (tenantProp == null)
                    continue;

                var entityParam = Expression.Parameter(entityType.ClrType, "e");

                var contextPropertyAccess = expression.Body;

                var propertyExpression = GetPropertyExpression(entityParam, tenantProp);
                if (propertyExpression.Type != contextPropertyAccess.Type)
                    propertyExpression = Expression.Convert(propertyExpression, contextPropertyAccess.Type);

                // ctx.Property == null || ctx.Property == e.Property
                var filterBody = (Expression) Expression.OrElse(
                    Expression.Equal(contextPropertyAccess, Expression.Default(contextPropertyAccess.Type)),
                    Expression.Equal(contextPropertyAccess, propertyExpression));

                filterBody = (Expression) Expression.Or(
                    filterBody,
                    Expression.Equal(propertyExpression, Expression.Default(contextPropertyAccess.Type)));

                var filterLambda = entityType.GetQueryFilter();

                // we have to combine filters
                if (filterLambda != null)
                {
                    filterBody = ReplacingExpressionVisitor.Replace(entityParam, filterLambda.Parameters[0], filterBody);
                    filterBody = Expression.AndAlso(filterLambda.Body, filterBody);
                    filterLambda = Expression.Lambda(filterBody, filterLambda.Parameters);
                }
                else
                {
                    filterLambda = Expression.Lambda(filterBody, entityParam);
                }

                entityType.SetQueryFilter(filterLambda);
            }
        }
    }

    private static Expression GetPropertyExpression(Expression objExpression, IProperty property)
    {
        Expression propExpression;
        if (property.PropertyInfo == null)
        {
            // 'property' is Shadow property, so call via EF.Property(e, "name")
            propExpression = Expression.Call(typeof(EF), nameof(EF.Property), new[] {property.ClrType},
                objExpression, Expression.Constant(property.Name));
        }
        else
        {
            propExpression = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(objExpression, property.PropertyInfo);
        }

        return propExpression;
    }
}
```

How can I do this?

I tried

```
filterBody = (Expression) Expression.Or(
                        filterBody,
                        Expression.Equal(propertyExpression, Expression.Default(contextPropertyAccess.Type)));
```

If I supply a Tenant ID, I need all of the records that match my tenant id to be returned OR the records where TenantId is null.  Originally I thought this didnt work, now it actually looks like it does, but is this the best approach?

Lets say we have 3 flats

Each Flat has a nullable property called TenantId

```
Flat 1 - TenantId 222
Flat 2 - TenantId 333
Flat 3 - TenantId NULL
```

Our DbContext has a property called TenantId

So if TenantId is 333 I want Flat 2 and Flat 3 to be returned.  Flat 3 because it has no TenantId

The idea of this approach is to have information available to all TenantIds, and other tied down to the specific tenant Id requested

I dont need to change the query filter on the fly

My generated SQL using TenantId and including records with null is really complex and potentially could be slow as well given that case statements in where clauses are not great

```
 WHERE ((CASE
          WHEN (@__ef_filter__p_0 = CAST(1 AS bit)) OR ((@__ef_filter__TenantId_1 = [b].[TenantId]) AND [b].[TenantId] IS NOT NULL) THEN CAST(1 AS bit)
          ELSE CAST(0 AS bit)
      END | CASE
          WHEN [b].[TenantId] IS NULL THEN CAST(1 AS bit)
          ELSE CAST(0 AS bit)
      END) = CAST(1 AS bit))
```

[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73121768/analyse-the-tables-involved-in-an-iqueryable)

Comment: *I now have a requirement where if the property in the record of the table is null I need to include it*, I do not understand this. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I'm messed up. As I remember If `TenantId` of `DbContext` is null, filter will return all records. Better approach is not possible in EF Core. You can define filter only during context configuring and there is no possibility to change it later.

Comment: My new requirement is to NOT exclude cases where the record has a TenantId of null - the logic for the context is fine

Answer (score 1):

Try simplify `filterBody` to the following:

```cs
var filterBody = (Expression) Expression.Equal(contextPropertyAccess, propertyExpression);
```

Corrected answer:

```cs
public static class ModelBuilderExtensions
{
   public static void ApplyQueryFiltersForProperties<TProp>(this ModelBuilder builder,
        Dictionary<string, Expression<Func<TProp>>> propertiesToFilter)
    {
        foreach (var (propertyName, expression) in propertiesToFilter)
        {
            foreach (var entityType in builder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
            {
                var tenantProp = entityType.GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == propertyName);
                if (tenantProp == null)
                    continue;

                var entityParam = Expression.Parameter(entityType.ClrType, "e");

                var contextPropertyAccess = expression.Body;

                var propertyExpression = GetPropertyExpression(entityParam, tenantProp);
                if (propertyExpression.Type != contextPropertyAccess.Type)
                    propertyExpression = Expression.Convert(propertyExpression, contextPropertyAccess.Type);

                // ctx.Property == e.Property
                var filterBody = (Expression) Expression.Equal(contextPropertyAccess, propertyExpression);

                var filterLambda = entityType.GetQueryFilter();

                // we have to combine filters
                if (filterLambda != null)
                {
                    filterBody = ReplacingExpressionVisitor.Replace(entityParam, filterLambda.Parameters[0], filterBody);
                    filterBody = Expression.AndAlso(filterLambda.Body, filterBody);
                    filterLambda = Expression.Lambda(filterBody, filterLambda.Parameters);
                }
                else
                {
                    filterLambda = Expression.Lambda(filterBody, entityParam);
                }

                entityType.SetQueryFilter(filterLambda);
            }
        }
    }

    private static Expression GetPropertyExpression(Expression objExpression, IProperty property)
    {
        Expression propExpression;
        if (property.PropertyInfo == null)
        {
            // 'property' is Shadow property, so call via EF.Property(e, "name")
            propExpression = Expression.Call(typeof(EF), nameof(EF.Property), new[] {property.ClrType},
                objExpression, Expression.Constant(property.Name));
        }
        else
        {
            propExpression = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(objExpression, property.PropertyInfo);
        }

        return propExpression;
    }
}
```

Comment: ok Im out at the moment, I will try when I get home, hopefully that will also keep the rest of logic intact as that works perfectly!

Comment: This doesnt work.  I have updated the question with the SQL that is generated with my "working" logic.  Although it works its really horrible looking at that generated SQL, I think that could end up being very slow!  Maybe there is an easier way

Comment: I mean left `filterBody` only this expression (No Or). SQL that you have shown is not reflect that. Also `Expression.Or` is bitwise operator, it should be `Expression.OrElse`

Comment: I am so confused! Could you update your answer with what you mean here please?  Your original answer here doesnt mention .OrElse?

Comment: Hello this logic is generating a query that check expecting null.  The TenantId check is not there.  Have I missed something?