# How to use IQueryExpressionInterceptor in EF Core 7 to inject a Where clause into query?

Tags: c#, reflection, entity-framework-core, authorization, interceptor

I am trying to use the new IQueryExpressionInterceptor interface to inject a `Where` clause into all my `Select` queries following this example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/whatsnew#linq-expression-tree-interception

The example is for a ThenBy clause that follows OrderBy, but I need a Where clause that follows Select. This is how far I have managed to get:

```cs
public class UserAccessFilteringExpressionInterceptor : IQueryExpressionInterceptor
{
    private AuthenticationStateProvider AuthStateProvider { get; }
    public IAuthorizationService AuthorizationService { get; }
    public UserAccessFilteringExpressionInterceptor(AuthenticationStateProvider authStateProvider, IAuthorizationService authorizationService)
    {
        AuthStateProvider = authStateProvider;
        AuthorizationService = authorizationService;
    }

    public Expression QueryCompilationStarting(Expression queryExpression, QueryExpressionEventData eventData)
        => new KeyOrderingExpressionVisitor(AuthStateProvider, AuthorizationService).Visit(queryExpression);

    private sealed class KeyOrderingExpressionVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        private AuthenticationStateProvider AuthStateProvider { get; set; }
        private IAuthorizationService AuthorizationService { get; }

        public KeyOrderingExpressionVisitor(AuthenticationStateProvider authStateProvider, IAuthorizationService authorizationService)
        {
            AuthStateProvider = authStateProvider;
            AuthorizationService = authorizationService;
        }

        private static readonly MethodInfo WhereMethodInfo = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods().First(m => m.Name == nameof(Queryable.Where));

        protected override Expression VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression? node)
        {
            var whereMethods = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods().Where(m => m.Name == nameof(Queryable.Where));

            var user = AuthStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync().Result.User;
            var userId = user.GetHomeObjectId();
            var manager = AuthorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(user, "RequireManagerRole").Result;

            var methodInfo = node!.Method;
            //Skip filtering if user is a manager
            //if (manager.Succeeded) return base.VisitMethodCall(node); //TODO: Re-enable this

            //Check if method is OrderBy
            if (methodInfo.DeclaringType == typeof(Queryable)
                && methodInfo.Name == nameof(Queryable.Select)
                && methodInfo.GetParameters().Length == 2)
            {
                //Get first argument for the node type
                var sourceType = node.Type.GetGenericArguments()[0];

                if (typeof(BaseDTO).IsAssignableFrom(sourceType))
                {
                    //Extract lambda expression of Select
                    var lambdaExpression = (LambdaExpression)((UnaryExpression)node.Arguments[1]).Operand;
                    //Extract parameter of the lambda expression Select(e => ...)
                    var entityParameterExpression = lambdaExpression.Parameters[0];
                    var test = Expression.Call(
                        method: WhereMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(sourceType, typeof(bool)),
                        arg0: base.VisitMethodCall(node),
                        arg1: Expression.Lambda(typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(entityParameterExpression.Type, typeof(bool)), //Create Func<Dto, bool>
                            Expression.Property(entityParameterExpression, nameof(BaseDTO.Id)),
                            true));
                    return test;
                }
            }

            return base.VisitMethodCall(node);
        }
    }
}
```

First problem is retrieving the correct MethodInfo for Where. The example differentiated overloads by simply counting inputs, but Where has two overloads with the same count. I tried `typeof(Queryable).GetMethod(nameof(Queryable.Where), new Type[] { typeof(IQueryable<object>), typeof(Expression<Func<object,bool>>) });` But it gives me null. Also I do not understand how to create the new predicate that is going to be `lambdaExpression.OwnerId == userId`.

Update: I read up on the global filters but it does not seem to be the right fit. I need to check the current role of the user before applying the filter.

Update2: For better clarification, I would like the interceptor to turn this:

```
DbContext.MyEntity
```

into:

```
DbContext.MyEntity.Where(entity => entity.OwnerId == userId)
```

But only in case user is not in Manager role. I already have that part though, it is just about the Expressions now.

Update3: This is what I have so far:

```
protected override Expression VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression? node)
{
    var whereMethods = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods().Where(m => m.Name == nameof(Queryable.Where));
    var user = AuthStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync().Result.User;
    
    var manager = AuthorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(user, "RequireManagerRole").Result;
    var methodInfo = node!.Method;
    //Skip filtering if user is a manager
    //if (manager.Succeeded) return base.VisitMethodCall(node); //TODO: Re-enable this
    var userIdString = user.GetHomeObjectId();
    if (userIdString is null)
    {
        throw new UnauthorizedAccessException($"User ID not found during DB query interception by {nameof(UserAccessFilteringExpressionInterceptor)}!");
    }
    var userId = Guid.Parse(userIdString);
    //Check if method is Select
    if (methodInfo.DeclaringType == typeof(Queryable)
        && methodInfo.Name == nameof(Queryable.Select)
        && methodInfo.GetParameters().Length == 2)
    {
        //Get first argument for the node type
        var sourceType = node.Type.GetGenericArguments()[0];
        if (typeof(TopicResumeDGDTO).IsAssignableFrom(sourceType))
        {
            //Extract lambda expression of Select
            var lambdaExpression = (LambdaExpression)((UnaryExpression)node.Arguments[1]).Operand;
            //Extract parameter of the lambda expression Select(e => ...)
            var entityParameterExpression = lambdaExpression.Parameters[0];
            var method = WhereMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(sourceType);
            var arg1 = Expression.Lambda(delegateType: typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(TopicResume), typeof(bool)), //Create Func<Dto, bool>
                    body: Expression.Equal(left: Expression.MakeMemberAccess(entityParameterExpression, typeof(TopicResume).GetMember(nameof(TopicResume.AadOwnerId)).Single()),
                    right: Expression.Convert(Expression.Constant(userId), typeof(Guid?))),
                    tailCall: true, parameters: entityParameterExpression);
            var test = Expression.Call(
                method: method,
                arg0: base.VisitMethodCall(node),
                arg1: arg1);
            return test;
        }
    }
    return base.VisitMethodCall(node);
}
```

Guru Stron's answer helped quite a bit but I am still stuck at building the new lambda expression. The problem is that the DTO types are clashing with DB types, and the whole thing is quite complex. I think I will solve this with a simpler approach for now and return later. Realistically even just modifying the built query string using DbCommandInterceptor would probably be easier.

Comment: Show which query to which variant you are trying to transform.

Comment: @Svyatoslav They are trying to inject filter, not to transform. OP: What you are trying is exactly what global query filters are, you don't need to play with interceptors and expressions, especially if you have no experience with expression tree manipulation.

Comment: @IvanStoev, I thought about Global Query filter, but maybe OP wants something other. I cannot understand from this sample what he is trying to build.

Comment: I have an application which accesses user data in database. I want people in manager role to be able to retrieve all the data while normal users should only see data that belongs to them. The global filters do look promising, I will look into that.

Answer (score 0):

Not a full answer but to target some specific problems

> First problem is retrieving the correct `MethodInfo` for `Where`

[`Queryable.Where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.where?view=net-7.0) is a generic method, so you need to match the generic parameter, for example using `Type.MakeGenericMethodParameter`:

```cs
var methodInfo = typeof(Queryable)
    .GetMethod(nameof(Queryable.Where), 
        new []
        {
            typeof(IQueryable<>).MakeGenericType(Type.MakeGenericMethodParameter(0)), 
            typeof(Expression<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(Type.MakeGenericMethodParameter(0), typeof(bool)))
        });
```

> Also I do not understand how to create the new predicate that is going to be `lambdaExpression.OwnerId == userId`

`Expression.Equal` represents the equality operation, "constants" (in context of the build expression) like `userId` are passed via `Expession.Constant`.

As for the whole goal - not sure that such rewrite is easily achievable this way, possibly it would be much easier to implement using aproach similar to [multitenancy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/multitenancy) (also check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47268072/ef-core-2-0-0-query-filter-is-caching-tenantid-updated-for-2-0-1))

Comment: Bravo. And how this will help them to achieve their goal. Reading questions before try answering would be a good idea.

Comment: Hey, I have added some closer clarification of my goal in the question, would you mind checking it out? Thx for your help BTW, you at least got me a little closer to my goal.