# Entity framework core OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)

Tags: entity-framework-core

I would like to retrieve the `Type` of entities that implement a specific interface. I want to retrive this inside the OnModelCreating method.

Example
Assume that I have the following entity

```
public class Product : IProductBase {
   public int ProductId {get;set;}
}
```

I also have a entity that does not implement `IProductBase` for example:

```
Public class ProductInventory {
  public int Id {get;set;}
}
```

In the following onModelCreating I want to be able to retrieve all the `Type(s)` of entities that have implemented `IProductBase` interface.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{


}
```

I have tried few things such as trying to retrieve the ClrType. But that does not seem to work.

Comment: Try `var type = typeof(IProductBase );
            var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
                .Where(p => type.IsAssignableFrom(p));` include namespaces `using System;
using System.Linq;`

Comment: 1 more question OnModelCreating is only called once right?

Comment: Once per each unique provider type. If you are targeting single database type (e.g. SqlServer), then it will be called once. Also, instead of iterating all the types in all assemblies, iterate just `modelBuilder.Mode.GetEntityTypes()` as shown here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45096799/filter-all-queries-trying-to-achieve-soft-delete/45097532#45097532

Comment: @John it will be called when you do `Update-Database` means when you try to apply migration. Let me know if you need help

Comment: @IvanStoev modelBuilder.Mode.GetEntityTypes() returns IMutableEntityType not the system.type which i need for reflection

Comment: Hi @IvanStoev tried following the question you linked. 
                                                                                                                   Getting following exception when ever I try to use the clrType property.    
                                                                                                    exception System.MissingMethodException: 'Method not found: 'System.Type Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.IEntityType.get_ClrType()'.'

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate the assemblies and get all the entities of type `IProductBase`.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

var type = typeof(IProductBase ); 
var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
.SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
.Where(p => type.IsAssignableFrom(p));
```

As suggested by @Ivan Stoev. You can also use the below method to get all the entities. Thank @Ivan for your valuable suggestions.

```
var type = modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes(typeof(FullAuditedEntity));
```